# Null pointer on run of class

Tags: java, swing

When I run this project, I get a NullPointer.

```
"Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at movieinfo.Swinggui.gui(Swinggui.java:71)
    at movieinfo.Swinggui.main(Swinggui.java:38)
"
```

It doesn't seem on those two lines, I am accessing that hadn't already been declared. 
I attempted setting breakpoints and debugging to fix it myself, to no avail.
Thanks for helping me, I really am not asking to be spoonfed.

```
package movieinfo;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.List;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Map;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JList;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;

import com.json.parsers.JSONParser;
import com.json.parsers.JsonParserFactory;


public class Swinggui {
    private static JButton enter;
    private static JTextField movietext;
    private static JTextArea movieinfo;
    private static JList listofmovies;//converts moviestowatch into gui element.
    private static File textfilemovie; //file which movies marked for watching are saved
    private static java.util.List<String> moviestowatch; //arraylist which is populated by textfilemovie than printed to GUI element.
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
yourMovies();
        gui();
        json();



    }
    public static void gui()
    {
        JFrame maingui = new JFrame("Gui");
        maingui.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.VERTICAL;
        enter = new JButton("Enter");
        c.gridx = 2;
        c.gridy = 1;
        maingui.add(enter, c);
        movieinfo = new JTextArea(5,20);
        movieinfo.setBorder(BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(2,2,2,2,Color.red));
        movietext = new JTextField(18);
        c.gridx = 1;
        c.gridy = 1;
        maingui.add(movietext, c);
        final JScrollPane scrolll = new JScrollPane(movieinfo);
        c.gridx = 1;
        c.gridy = 3;
        c.gridwidth = 2;
        maingui.add(scrolll, c);
        final JLabel titlee = new JLabel("Enter movie name below!");
        c.gridx = 1;
        c.gridy = 0;
        maingui.add(titlee, c);
        maingui.setResizable(false);
        maingui.setVisible(true);
        listofmovies = new JList(moviestowatch.toArray());
        c.gridx = 4;
        c.gridy = 3;
        maingui.add(new JScrollPane(listofmovies), c);
        movieinfo.setLineWrap(true);
        movieinfo.setWrapStyleWord(true);
        movieinfo.setEditable(false);
        scrolll.getPreferredSize();
        //pangui.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 150));
        //pangui.add(scrolll, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        //movieinfo.add(scrolll);
        maingui.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        maingui.pack();

    }
    public static void json()
    {
        enter.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){

            private JsonParserFactory factory;
            private JSONParser parser;
            @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
            private Map jsonData;

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)  
            {
                System.out.println(apicall.getMovieInfo(movietext.getText()));
                factory = JsonParserFactory.getInstance();
                parser = factory.newJsonParser();
                jsonData = parser.parseJson(apicall.getMovieInfo(movietext.getText()));
                String Title = (String)jsonData.get("Title");
                String Year = (String)jsonData.get("Year");
                String Plot = (String)jsonData.get("Plot");
                movieinfo.setText("Title: "+Title+"\nYear: "+ Year +"\nPlot: "+Plot);
            }
        });
    }
    public static void yourMovies() throws IOException
    {
        textfilemovie = new File(org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.getUserDirectory() + "/yourmovies.txt");

        textfilemovie.createNewFile();
        moviestowatch = FileUtils.readLines(textfilemovie);
        while (listofmovies.getSelectedValue().toString()!= null)
        {
            movietext.setText(listofmovies.getSelectedValue().toString());
            enter.doClick();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Which line is 71 of the class Swinggui.java? That's where you're trying to de-reference (usually call a method on) a variable with a null reference.

Comment: listofmovies = new JList(moviestowatch.toArray()); is line 71.

Comment: `moviestowatch` is null. Now back track to see why.

Comment: If I remove the while loop
 while (listofmovies.getSelectedValue().toString()!= null)
        {
            movietext.setText(listofmovies.getSelectedValue().toString());
            enter.doClick();
        }
the nullpointer disappears. I've not a clue why, as per the fact I'm not even referencing movies to watch (line 71).

Comment: I don't see why moviestowatch becomes null only if that whileloop is there. Honestly makes no sense to me.

Comment: You've a new NPE now. Why assume that it's the same variable causing it? Check the variables on the line causing the new NPE and see for yourself which is null. My bet that you're trying to "click" a button that has yet to be rendered. Again, that code in the while loop makes no sense.

Comment: I've concluded it's an issue with "listofmovies.getSelectedValue().toString()!= null"

Comment: I'll have to think of another way to do this, though I don't see why "listofmovies.getSelectedValue().toString()!= null" is not okay.

Comment: (I removed the do.click, and still got the error).

Comment: I declare the value of listofmovies in the Gui() class.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're calling gui() **before** calling yourMovies() so do not initialize the ArrayList before using it.

But that is not what is important here. No, what is important is that you recognize the process of how to debug a NPE on your own:

- Check the line that throws the NPE
- Find the variable on that line that is null
- Then search back into the code to see why it is null when you think that it shouldn't be.

Usually these errors are easy to fix once you know how.

Your other problems include:

- You are over-using static. Your code has no "*state*", no true OOPs classes, and this will limit your ability to extend and improve your code. The only static method should be the main method, and this should only contain code to set up your classes and start them, and that's it.
- Your json code should be in a class of its own, separate from the GUI class. This will allow you to debug and enhance it in isolation from completely unrelated code. Look up cohesion and coupling. You want your class cohesion to be high and coupling to be low: keep related stuff together and unrelated stuff apart.
- Your while loop, `while (listofmovies.getSelectedValue().toString()!= null)...` makes no sense in its current location. You shouldn't be calling `doClick()` on a GUI's buttons while it's in the process of being created, of being built, and before it is rendered.
- Your code is thrown together without planning. Much better would be to write out the structure of your program on paper first before committing any code.

Comment: I saw that. I was trying to backtrace to get rid of the nullpointer and accidentally posted this code before I fixed it.

Comment: I'm getting the same nullpointer @ line 115. while (listofmovies.getSelectedValue().toString()!= null)
  {
   movietext.setText(listofmovies.getSelectedValue().toString());
   enter.doClick();
  }

Comment: @EricLang: see edit to answer. Your while loop's contents are questionable.

Comment: I see, but I can't call Gui() (else I get the nullpointer) first, I completely understand the enter button hadn't been created yet.

Comment: @EricLang: you shouldn't even be trying to click anything there. Re-plan, re-write.

Answer (score 3):

> It doesn't seem on those two lines, I am accessing that hadn't already
>   been declared.

Believe the JVM.  If it says there's a NPE at that line, then it's true.  Your "seem" is a bad assumption.

> I attempted setting breakpoints and debugging to fix it myself, to no
>   avail.

Sounds like you need to learn how to set breakpoints in your IDE.  That will sort it out quickly if you do it properly.  Which one are you using?

> Thanks for helping me, I really am not asking to be spoonfed.

Unfortunately, you *are* asking to be spoonfed.

Comment: I actually already found the issue with my constructor, I thought I had fixed it in the code I posted, but I didn't.
How am I asking to be spoonfed, I quite literally see nothing wrong with "while (listofmovies.getSelectedValue().toString()!= null)
  {
   movietext.setText(listofmovies.getSelectedValue().toString());
   enter.doClick();
  }
"

Comment: You should get used to deferring to the VM when it says a pointer is null. When you see nothing wrong with code that does fail, you have something to learn about your code.

Answer (score 2):

Your `moviestowatch` is not initialised.

You are calling `yourMovies()` to initialise `moviestowatch`.

But you are trying to access `moviestowatch` in `gui()`.

Answer (score 2):

you have declared moviestowatch at line 35

```
private static java.util.List<String> moviestowatch; //arraylist which is populated by textfilemovie than printed to GUI element.
```

and used it at line 71 in function gui()

```
    listofmovies = new JList(moviestowatch.toArray());
```

initialize it before using it.

the sequence of calling function is

```
  gui();
  json();
  yourMovies();
```

your list is initializing in   yourMovies() method.and you are using it in gui() method. so call yourMovies() method before calling gui() method which actually using it.

**EDIT:**

your next error is  getting a nullpointer @ line 115 in the following while loop.

To solve above error what you have done is changed the sequence and called yourMovies() before gui(). but Here you have initialized listofmovies list in gui and used in yourMovies() method :).

It is general programming practice that for all list/object you have to manually check that everytime before you use. it should be initialized before using it. otherwise it will throw NPE.

Comment: I had already fixed that error, I am getting a nullpointer @ line 115 in the following while loop.

Comment: while (listofmovies.getSelectedValue().toString()!= null)
  {
   movietext.setText(listofmovies.getSelectedValue().toString());
   enter.doClick();
  }

Comment: what you have done is changed the sequence of calling function ?

Comment: Here you have initialized listofmovies list in gui and used in yourMovies() method.

Comment: for all list you  have to manually check that everytime you use it should be initialized before using it.

Answer (score -2):

If you get NullPointerException it always mean that one of your classes fields was not initialized. There is no way you will get NPE with local reference variable because compiler will warn you. I myself try to initialize everything that does not require additional input on the line where I am declaring it and this practice saved me a lot of NPE. And this is usuful especially with containers.

Comment: `"There is no way you will get NPE with local reference variable because compiler will warn you."` -- this is simply not true. Yes, you must always assign to a local variable before using it, but that assignment may be null.

Comment: Yeah you are right that sentence of mine is  ambiguous because it lacks one word ' decklaration '. It should be formed the following way: There is no way you can get NPE with local reference variable declaration ( not to be confused with definition ) because that is simply forbidden by compiler. Any local variable must be initialized ( in Java ) and yes local reference variables can be set to null and then it is possible to get NPE trying to invoke a method on that variable.